# Pass a list of strings to a command line argument within a script with pipe in python

Tags: python, list, command-line, pipe, except

Unsure if this is possible. But it seems that anything is possible when it comes to programming(:

I have a **list** of **strings** for example:
 ['one', 'two' , 'three', 'four'....]
The number of items is technically unknown---'n'--- and will change depending what is passed into the list from a text file elsewhere.

I need to take these items from the list and pass them in as **command line arguments** within a script, not in the python shell or any CLI (for now I am just working with the python shell). I also need to **pipe** it and use the **'except'** command.

So it will look like the following, this is **required**. I know there are other ways to do this, but this is the structure I am looking for:

show "file name" | except one | except two | except three | except four |.....| except 'n'

Basically show the text file in the shell except for these items of text in the file.

Is there actually a way to do this? I am unfamiliar with python to this extent.
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: are you asking about sys.args?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here, but you can create the command you want as follows and then use `os.system` to execute that command:

```
import os

arguments =  ['one', 'two' , 'three', 'four']
arguments = " ".join(list(map(lambda i: "| except " + i, arguments)))
filename = "file name"
command = "show"

command = " ".join([command, filename, arguments])
print(command)

# show file name | except one | except two | except three | except four

os.system(command)
```